# jQuery parent().("selector")

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this HTML code:

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="chk" /></td>
  <td><div class="disabled">text to hide 1</div></td>
  <td><div class="disabled">text to hide 2</div></td>
</tr>
```

I'm using jQuery to hide all `class="disabled"` items:

```
$("div.disabled").hide() ;
```

I want to show disabled divs when I click the checkbox in the same row (tr).
I tried

```
$("input.chk").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().(".disabled").show();
}) ;
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), like this:

```
$("input.chk").click(function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find(".disabled").show();
});
```

Your current code *almost* works, you need a [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) though, like this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find(".disabled").show();
```

If you have *many* rows like this, use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), like this:

```
$("table").delegate("input.chk", "click", function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find(".disabled").show();
});
```

[`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead binds one handler to the table for all of the `input.chk` elements to bubble up to.  If you're looking to enable/disable, use `change` and [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) in addition to the above, like this:

```
$("table").delegate("input.chk", "change", function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find(".disabled").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

This way if it's checked they show, if not they hide.

Comment: .closest() got deprecated and removed in 1.8
http://api.jquery.com/closest/  (see bottom of page) Look for http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/

Comment: If you actually look at the link, closest is not deprecated, just one particular signature. I see nothing to indicate a preference for parentsUntil over closest.

Comment: .closest(), worked well, even the parent().parent().parent() was working, but closest did the trick.. and its shorter code

Answer (score 3):

Yes using `find()` and `closest()` is definitely the right procedure. There is a different style of writing the same. The code snippet is here.

```
$("input.chk").click(function() {
      var th = $(this);
      $(".disabled", th.parent().parent()).show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost. You're just missing the word `find` to indicate [jQuery's `.find()` method](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

```
$("input.chk").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".disabled").show();
}) ;
```

Or, a little shorter version is to [use `.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

```
$("input.chk").click(function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find(".disabled").show();
});
```

You could also [use `.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/), though you would want to indicate [the `:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector) match in case you have nested tables.

```
$("input.chk").click(function(){
  $(this).parents('tr:first').find(".disabled").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its actually even easier than that.

```
    $(".disabled").hide();
    $(".chk").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            $(this).siblings(".disabled").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).siblings(".disabled").hide();
        }
    });
```

I even added some extra functionality so that the event didn't just trigger once, but rather toggles based on whether the check box is checked or not.

Comment: The elements aren't siblings, they're in different table cells :) *if* they were, the short method would be: `$(".chk").change(function() { $(this).siblings(".disabled").toggle(this.checked); });`

Comment: I assumed they were siblings because they were on the same level contained in a shared parent.  I was following your conversation with nubbel and you're right, I was doing the same thing with a <tr> and no <table>.

Answer (score 0):

And it's even easier:

```
$(".disabled").hide();
$(".chk").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".disabled").toggle();
});​
```

:-)

Comment: As I commented on the other answer (besides this one doesn't account for initial state), the `.disabled` elements are not siblings :)

Comment: I thought so and was about to comment Eric, but I tried it out: http://jsfiddle.net/jpQcu/. It seems like `$.siblings()` returns elements which are in the same depth of the tree. I think `$.nextAll()` is what we meant.

Comment: @nubbel - `.nextAll()` is also *only* for siblings :)

Comment: @nubbel - It doesn't... http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/WAQBj/ Your solution only appears to work because of invalid markup, placing a `<tr>` directly in the `<body>` causing all sorts of mess :)

Answer (score 0):

Now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/WAQBj/2/

```
$(".disabled").hide();
$(".chk").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find(".disabled").toggle();
});​
```